# How do I select all occurrences of current selection in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

In VSCode there is a shortcut for selecting all occurrences of current selection. It is used by default with `Ctrl + Shift + L`.

When you select a word and you press it, you automatically select all the occurrences too.

What is the alternative for IntelliJ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shift + Ctrl + Alt + J
https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/intellij-idea-13-1-rc-introduces-sublime-text-style-multiple-selections/#:~:targetText=Add%2Fremove%20a%20selection%3A%20Alt,G%20for%20Mac%20OS%20X)

Alt + J for next selection only

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using VSCode keymap, it is Ctrl+F2 or Ctrl+Shift+L.
You can change the mapping from File > Settings > Keymap > Main Menu > Edit > Find > Select All Occurunses